# Unity3d объект проходит сквозь другие объекты

Tags: unity3d

Есть cube с бокс коллайдером. При движении этого куба он проходит сквозь стены (которые тоже имеют бокс коллайдер).
Код для движения cube

```
    public class RocketMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3.0f;
    private float deltaX;
    private float deltaZ;
    private Component collider;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        collider = this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        this.transform.position = new Vector3(ray.GetPoint(10f).x, this.transform.position.y, ray.GetPoint(10f).z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас здесь не работает физика. Вы просто перемещаете объект в новую позицию. Для того чтобы физика функционировала надо на объект вешать [RigidBody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html) и к нему прикладывать силы.

Comment: Добавил RigidBody - то же самое.

Comment: Объект перемещаете используя [Rigidbody.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) ? Если вы продолжаете изменять положение через `this.transform.position = new Vector3(ray.GetPoint(10f).x, this.transform.position.y, ray.GetPoint(10f).z);` то физика по прежнему не будет работать.

Comment: Пытаюсь переместить объект с помощью AddForce - он просто пропадает

Comment: Киньте ссылку на проект попробую посмотреть, больше ничего предложить не могу на вскидку

Comment: Еще пара типичных вещей:

`Rigidbody.AddForce()` следует делать в `FixedUpdate()`, вместо `Update()`.

Гравитацию нужно выключить, а то он может из-за этого исчезает, просто быстро падая за границы кадра.

Answer (score 0):

Пытаться ограничить объект коллайдерами, когда ты этот объект двигаешь мышкой, заведомо не правильно. У тебя может быть ситуация , когда в кадр до границы у тебя коллайдер того, что ты двигаешь, будет еще до границы, а в следующем кадре - уже за границей.. Здесь надо просто на координаты смотреть и не давать им выйти за нужный диапазон. Можно конечно и collision detection поставить Continious Dynamic, но и в этом случае могут быть такие же баги , как у тебя. К тому же дороже будет.

А про физику столкновений здесь https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html есть таблица, что с чем сталкивается или на что срабатывает триггер. Слои еще у коллайдеров должны быть те, которые реагируют друг с другом. В ProjectSettings настроивается..

И еще, если всё-таки будешь двигать объект с RigidBody, то делать это надо в FixedUpdate() через методы RigidBody, если он не isKinematic. Если isKinematic не включен и будешь двигать тупо меняя координаты, то получишь серьезный урон по производительности. Если isKinematic , то можно и в Update() двигать 'координатами'.

И еще не понятно зачем ты создаешь луч, потом на нем еще что-то откладываешь каждый раз, просто чтобы координаты мышки перевести в мировые? Почему просто не

`Vector3 mPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
 mPos.y = 'твое значение';
 transform.position = mPos`

Ну это так.. придирки